# Cordova : Open the app when user is some distance away from particular position

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap

My app is taxi riding app. and my client requirement is that if the application is in background or killed, then it start automatically and come in foreground when user is 100 meter away from destination.
The app is in Cordova/Ionic.

Comment: You can't do that on iOS. You can use CLRegion on iOS to monitor for when the driver is within 150m (minimum radius as I recall) and run a UILocalNotification. Using CLRegion is one of the only methods to actually run a terminated app

Comment: I think it's very bad practice to start an app for this kind of purpose especially if it's been killed. If I had an app that just started itself after I killed it, it'd be an instant uninstall.